# Arraylist does not take parameters JAVA

Tags: java

The documentation says arraylist does not take parameters and I am not sure what todo to correct it.

```
package arraylist;

public class ArrayList {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    weeklyTemperatures.add(78);
    weeklyTemperatures.add(67);
    weeklyTemperatures.add(89);
    weeklyTemperatures.add(94);
    weeklyTemperatures.add(2, 111);
    System.out.println(weeklyTemperatures.get(3));
  }
}
```

Comment: Rename your Main class "public class ArrayList" to something else

Answer (score 1):

You named your public class `ArrayList` which is already a class and you are redefining it. Try naming it something like

```
public class ArrayListProgram
```

and it should work.

Comment: It's not exactly a reserved word. It just prevents the default import suggestion of the `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Nope that doesn't work still says same problem

Comment: @Chris.A I'm afraid, yes it does.

Comment: @Chris.A Did you rename your class and `.java` file? Did you recompile it? Did you try to run recompiled version?

Comment: I started fresh and made a new project called Temperatures and w it works fine and I can import that java.util thing. thanks everybody!! :)

Comment: reserved word is the wrong word. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Your code as is can not compile because you shadow `java.util.ArrayList`. Rename your class, then

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```